# Highlight Based on Search witihn Range of Cell Values for Partial Text Based on Another Sheet Range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a "Sheet 1" were each Cell in Range A1 to A100 contains Text with Numbers separated by Forward Slash (/)....Like A1 contains 999/888/Test and A2 Contains 666/222/Hello etc

I have another "Sheet 2" Where Range B1 to B100 contains Only Number like..
B1 Contains 666,B2 Contains 222 ,etc

I want to Highlight Cells in Sheet1 (Range A1 to A100) that Contain Any Numbers from Sheet 2 (Range B1 to B100)

Any Soln ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility:

[image]

Steps I took:

- Select `A1:A3`
- Under Conditional Formatting, use a formula:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]")=TRANSPOSE($B$1:$B$2)))>0
  ```
- Apply your prefered formatting and accept.

---

Note, it can be done through a shorter formula but `FILTERXML()` acts as sort of an "split" function to return only numeric nodes from our string. Then we simply check if any of those nodes exists in column B through `SUMPRODUCT()`.

---

Same concept, different ranges:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]")=TRANSPOSE($B$1:$B$5)))>0
```

Comment: It is only taking adjacent value and not entire Range like B:B50

Comment: @mohanishSanghavi, no it doesn't